# How to cache GridSearchCV optimizer result in Google Colab?

Tags: gridsearchcv, colab

I have to execute `GridSearchCV()` cell every time I reload the page and it takes a lot of time. Is there a caching mechanism which stores the GridSearchCV result so that I can use it without executing the cell on the reload?

Code:

```
 neigh_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
 grid_search = GridSearchCV(neigh_clf, param_grid, cv=5,verbose=3,n_jobs=-1)
 grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
 grid_search.best_params_
```

I am trying to save grid_search object here so that I can retrieve best_params_ value after reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can save the trained model or any other file via Google Colaboratory.

**How I'm using it?**

> I have mapped my Google Drive with Google Colaboratory notebook and
>   saved trained model as a pickle file in it. You can create a file and save your data in it.

**How to integrate Google Drive with Google Colaboratory notebook?**

```
#Add and execute below mentioned line of code in Google colaboratory notebook cell.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('ndrive')
#Once you execute these two lines, it will ask you to authorize it. Please follow the steps as visible on the Google Colaboratory Notebook.
```

That's it :).

> **Few important points:**
>
> 1. Now you can run usual linux command to browse the directories.
> 2. By default it mapped to **content** folder and you can create sub directories in it.
> 3. You can visit these sub-directories via Google-Drive application as well.

Comment: I have updated the description with the code. I am trying to save grid_search object so that I can retrieve best_params_ object. Pickle doesnot work for grid_search and pickling  neigh_clf doesnt give me best_params_

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that part clearly, but using pickle you can dump anything you want. For example: f1 = open("attribute.pkl","wb")
    pk.dump(grid_search.best_params_, f1), or event best KNN model i.e. f2 = open("Knn.pkl","wb")
    pk.dump(grid_search.estimator, f2)

Comment: i thought only models could be saved using pickle. Tried it out and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Welcome and all the best.